# How to create another issuer for another subdomain in Kubernetes using Nginx-ingress controller?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am trying to create another Issuer can for another subdomain.  I am following this example: [Digital Ocean Kubernetes tutorial](https://github.com/digitalocean/Kubernetes-Starter-Kit-Developers/blob/main/03-setup-ingress-controller/nginx.md) and in this example the author gives an example for the http://echo.starter-kit.online/ subdomain which I was able to get working using my own subdomain.

I am trying to get this working for the quote.starter-kit.online example by creating a new Issuer like following:

```
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: quote-letsencrypt-nginx
  namespace: backend
spec:
  # ACME issuer configuration
  # `email` - the email address to be associated with the ACME account (make sure it's a valid one)
  # `server` - the URL used to access the ACME server’s directory endpoint
  # `privateKeySecretRef` - Kubernetes Secret to store the automatically generated ACME account private key
  acme:
    email: my@mydomain.com
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: quote-letsencrypt-nginx-private-key
    solvers:
      # Use the HTTP-01 challenge provider
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
```

And the following Ingress rule for the quote subdomain:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-quote
  namespace: backend
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt-nginx
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - quote.mydomain.com
    secretName: quote-letsencrypt
  rules:
    - host: quote.mydomain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: quote
                port:
                  number: 8080
  ingressClassName: nginx
```

when I do the following:

```
>kubectl get certificates -n backend
NAME                      READY   SECRET                    AGE
letsencrypt-nginx         True    letsencrypt-nginx         5d2h
quote-letsencrypt-nginx   False   quote-letsencrypt-nginx   2s
```

I can see the certs.  However, when I do the following I see the https is not working:

```
 curl -Li quote.mydomain.com         
HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect
Date: Sun, 02 Jan 2022 23:49:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 164
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://quote.mydomain.com

curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-quote
  namespace: backend
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/issuer: quote-letsencrypt-nginx  # <-- changed
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - quote.mydomain.com
    secretName: quote-letsencrypt-tls
  rules:
    ...
```

Comment: secretName: <the name as in your certificate spec.secretName> :  In that tutorial the cert gets created from that Ingress yaml file.  Can that name be any?

Comment: Can. Note `kubectl get certificates -n backend` in your question shown READY as False, this means the request for certificate was not fulfilled. In this case do a `kubectl describe certificate quote-letsencrypt-tls` and paste the Events section to your question.